# varnish 5.0 varnishstat show empty response with parameter f

Tags: varnish, varnish-4

I have a problem with varnishtat, who return empty solution with the f parameter.

I plan to use varnishstat to monitor varnish, like that :

```
varnishstat  -f MAIN.uptime
```

on previous version of varnish, like 4.0.3, there is no problem, i receive the value into console or inline. But on varnish as soon as i use the f parameter, the answer is empty.

if i use like that:

```
varnishstat  -f MAIN.*
```

it works perfectly, but if i want to target a specific value, i have a empty response in return.

do you have a way to have the response of varnistat as usual ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

i reply to my own question :)

seems in varnish5 need double the .

it means, before it's possible to use like that: 
varnishstat  -f MAIN.uptime

now in Varnish 5, need use like that :

varnishstat  -f MAIN..uptime